# How to align bootstrap grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a twitter grid, I have some grid spans that have a larger height then others and on each row of the grid the spans are pushed down. What I would like to do is have the items to appear under the over items. I have taken a screen shot of what it looks like and I have photoshopped how i would like it. Screenshots below.

[Here is the original](http://i43.tinypic.com/e7l155.png)

[Here is the photoshoped](http://i39.tinypic.com/2j5hy6h.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 overall approaches to Bootstrap grid alignment / height issues..

A CSS only approach like this this..

http://bootply.com/85737

A 'clearfix' (responsive reset) approach like this this (requires iteration every x columns)..

http://bootply.com/89910

Finally you may want to use the Isotope/Masonry plugin. Here is a working example that uses Isotope + Bootstrap..

http://bootply.com/61482

Comment: Thank you very much i used the isotope/masonry plugin it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue as grid elements have to be in rows so first and last will loose left and right padding respectively.

Workaround I use:
- if there is a set number of grid elements per row then I don't include `<div class='row'>`, just the gridded elements, and then remove the extra padding with nth-child() property of every third and fourth element (in case there are three gridded elements)

Also you could try using [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)