# Bootstrap Grid Layout Tip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I have to develop from a PHP function an HTML layout like this: 
[image]
Actually, each rectangle is inside a col-lg-4. Naturally, the result is something like that: 
[image]

I don't know what dimensions the different sector will have, but the second row is aligned directly on the bottom of the higher rectangle (I'd prefer to have them exactly like in the first image).

Would you have some tips ? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The HTML developed is something like that:

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-lg-4">    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is about the last two div

Comment: To understand your issue it's always good to share some code sample you are using.

Comment: @DebRaj The HTML is developed inside a PHP function. Basically, it develops something like that (see the code in the post)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530448/how-to-align-bootstrap-grids/20530918#20530918

Comment: I solved it, thanks @Skelly !